# Cannot find /js/highcharts.js in GWT project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, highcharts

I am working on displaying charts in my GWT project but somehow I cannot get highcharts to work. I have the following html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="StockWeather.css">

    <title>Web Application Starter Project</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="stockweather/stockweather.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>

    <noscript>
      <div style="width: 22em; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -11em; color: red; background-color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 4px; font-family: sans-serif">
        Your web browser must have JavaScript enabled
        in order for this application to display correctly.
      </div>
    </noscript>

    <h1>Web Application Starter Project</h1>  
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="font-weight:bold;">Please enter your name:</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="nameFieldContainer"></td>
        <td id="sendButtonContainer"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="color:red;" id="errorLabelContainer"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

with this directory structure :

```
├── gfx
│   └── vml-radial-gradient.png
├── graphics
│   ├── skies.jpg
│   ├── snow.png
│   └── sun.png
├── gwt-unitCache
│   ├── gwt-unitCache-000........
├── index.htm
├── js
│   ├── adapters
│   │   ├── mootools-adapter.js
│   │   ├── mootools-adapter.src.js
│   │   ├── prototype-adapter.js
│   │   └── prototype-adapter.src.js
│   ├── highcharts.js
│   ├── highcharts-more.js
│   ├── highcharts.src.js
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── canvas-tools.js
│   │   ├── canvas-tools.src.js
│   │   ├── data.js
│   │   ├── data.src.js
│   │   ├── exporting.js
│   │   └── exporting.src.js
│   └── themes
│       ├── dark-blue.js
│       ├── dark-green.js
│       ├── gray.js
│       ├── grid.js
│       └── skies.js
├── src
│   ├── com
│   │   └── example
│   ├── gfx
│   │   └── vml-radial-gradient.png
│   ├── graphics
│   │   ├── skies.jpg
│   │   ├── snow.png
│   │   └── sun.png
│   ├── index.htm
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── adapters
│   │   ├── highcharts.js
│   │   ├── highcharts-more.js
│   │   ├── highcharts.src.js
│   │   ├── modules
│   │   └── themes
│   ├── log4j.properties
│   └── META-INF
│       ├── jdoconfig.xml
│       └── persistence.xml
├── test
│   └── com
│       └── example
├── test-classes
│   └── com
│       └── example
└── war
    ├── favicon.ico
    ├── stockweather
    │   ├── ..........
    ├── StockWeather.css
    ├── StockWeather.html
    └── WEB-INF
        ├── appengine-web.xml
        ├── classes
        ├── deploy
        ├── lib
        ├── logging.properties
        └── web.xml
```

I am getting this error on running this application:

> Jun 12, 2013 9:28:02 PM
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
>   WARNING: No file found for: /js/highcharts.js

I have `org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.5.0.jar` added to project.

What should I do more  ? Where should I place `highcharts.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all your static content inside the `war` root directory. In this case, in a `js` directory.

UPDATE: In fact, all the content that you want available for the webapp. Just remember that configuration and libraries/classes goes into the `WEB-INF` subdirectory and it is not directly reachable (do not put static content there).

Comment: Noticed that just after posting this question :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the url to your application is,

```
http://your.domain/subpath/index.htm
```

I would check if

```
http://your.domain/subpath/js/highcharts.js
```

reach the highcharts.js file